# Why I can not call javascript function after load inside updatepanel?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I can not call javascript function after page load inside update panel:

Here is my UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode ="Conditional"  runat="server" >
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonLoadGridView" />                  
    </Triggers>                
 <ContentTemplate>`
```

My Button:

```
protected void ButtonLoadGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = "dsData";
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Here is javascript function:

```
window.onload = function ti() {     
    document.getElementById('<%= Label_Clients.ClientID %>').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    alert("You data is loaded');
}
```

I have tried this:

```
<script>      
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(windows.onload;
</script>
```

The problem is that after loading gridview on button click will not call javascript windows.onload function just only when use PostBackTrigger instead of AsyncPostbackTrigger please help me!

GetIstance it triggers MyFunction() this way just when I put other buttons those trigger MyFunction() too which I do not want:

```
      window.onload = function ti() 
    {     
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(MyFunction);
    
        function MyFunction()
        {
            document.getElementById('<%= Label_Clients.ClientID %>').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
            alert("You data is loaded');
            }
        }
```

I need to use readystate on GridView1 to trigger MyFunction() only when Button1 fires I need something like this:

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
            if (document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').readyState !== "complete") 
        
        {
            
            
            
            window.onload = function ti() 
        {     
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
                   prm.add_endRequest(MyFunction);
    
        
        function MyFunction()
        {
                document.getElementById('<%= Label_Clients.ClientID %>').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
                alert("You data is loaded');
                           }
                       }
                  }
            }
```

But the problem this way this doesn`t work what to do??

Answer (score 0):

The simples solution would be to create a separate function that is called on page load and on UpdatePanel load.
ps you have a double and single quote in the `alert()` part.

```
<script>
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    //this code is executed after the UpdatePanel has finished loading.
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        MyFunction();
    });

    //normal window.onload
    window.onload = function ti() {
        MyFunction();
    }

    //the javascript you want executed on page load and updatepanel
    function MyFunction() {
        document.getElementById('<%= Label_Clients.ClientID %>').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        alert('You data is loaded');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesnt work it gives the same results :(

Answer (score 0):

ok, so with a update panel, then only "part of" the page goes through the standard page life cycle.

So, your idea to "attach" the event using GetInstance looks to be the correct road.

I would try this syntax:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
//this code is executed after the UpdatePanel has finished loading.
prm.add_endRequest(MyFunction);
```

The above should trigger/run your "MyFunction".

Comment: It works but the problem when put other buttons those trigger this MyFunction() too, I have used readystate on GridView1  so when I click on other buttons it will not fire MyFucntion() please can you help me I edited my post.